# How to check if record is exist based on some Id in db using mule esb

Tags: database, mule

How to check existing Customerid in db using mule esb. I am inserting the data customer table in db, In this customerid is unique. When I insert the data I am unable to find the already existing Customer Id Using mule flow. Please anyone suggest on this. I am getting data as Json format from Rest api.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass your **select** query to **database connector**.
        If there is an **existing record**  you will be getting value out of your query                   or else you will be returning **empty**.
            use  a **choice router** to check for emptiness.
            If result is empty then there is no record exist.
            Based on that you can proceed further.

Cheers!

Comment: Thank vijay, I tried to whatever you said. Now its working fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in below way:

1. Use the corresponding DBConnector and get the value based on Id, if returns then value is exist.
2. If you DB is connected with any application and that application has SOAP/ REST services, then by using those as Endpoint in mule, you can check it in muleflow by setting some payload for checking the Uniqueness.

Answer (score 0):

You can first query the db to check if the customerId exist. If its not there then inserts, if its there then use update.